# Perl: How to get the value of an attribute of an object

Tags: perl

In the below example, how would i print out the thread id?

```
  $r_event = {
            'type'      => 'READ_' . $task . '_STARTED',
            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
            'threadid'  => $threadId,
            'fdn'       => $fdn
        };
```

Comment: There are no attributes and no objects in your example.

Comment: Some other languages call such a thing "object".

Answer (score 4):

You have a hash reference there (and those are often used as objects and that's what JSON calls an "object"). You can use the `->` to dereference it and put the key you want in curlies:

```
print $r_event->{'threaded'};
```

This is just like a normal hash. Note the `%` and the parens instead of curlies:

```
  %r_event = (
            'type'      => 'READ_' . $task . '_STARTED',
            'timestamp' => $timestamp,
            'threadid'  => $threadId,
            'fdn'       => $fdn
        );
```

In that case it's just `$r_event{'threaded'}` with no arrow since there's no reference.

My book [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com) covers this and you'll also find it in [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html).